# Is there a linker flag to force it to load all shared libraries at start time?

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, linker, ld, libc

Is there a flag or any other directive that I can use to force the Linux Dynamic Linker `ld.so` to load all shared libraries at once at start of the program instead of [lazy binding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55846/elf-shared-libraries-motivation-for-the-plt).

Essentially I want to turn off lazy binding.

Thanks

Comment: Dynamic Libraries can be instructed to load at system startup by setting the `LD_BIND_NOW` variable with ld.so, the dynamic linker/loader. Is it `LD_BIND_NOW` that you are looking for?

Comment: @skwllsp So If I set the environment variable LD_BIND_NOW =1. This will make the linker bind and load all the DSO at start of the program?

Comment: Yes, it will. Use the `LD_DEBUG` variable if you doubt to check and make sure that the dynamic lynker does it.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer so that I can accept it thanks

Comment: so if any dynamic link is not resolvable at start up, what is the expectation; an error message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting environment variable `LD_BIND_NOW = 1` will do that.

Thanks to @skwllsp for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

man ld sayes:

> **-z keyword**
>
> **now**  - When generating an executable or shared library, mark it to tell the dynamic linker to resolve all symbols when the program
>   is started, or when the shared library is linked to using dlopen,
>   instead of deferring function call resolution to the point when the
>   function is first called

http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld

Comment: I do not have control over the compilation of shared libraries that I am using. I am looking for an option that will instruct linker to load all the normal shared libraries needed by at start time.

Comment: @abhi: Your question asks for a linker option, but it seems like you actually wanted a loader option.